# Stange behaviour using nanoflann

Tags: c++, kdtree, flann

Using the [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann)-library for k-nearest-neighbor searches based on KDTrees I encountered a very strange behavior. My Code is a simple set of queries:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <nanoflann.hpp>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixX3d;
using Eigen::Vector3d;

using nanoflann::KNNResultSet;
using nanoflann::SearchParams;
using kdt = nanoflann::KDTreeEigenMatrixAdaptor<MatrixX3d, 3, nanoflann::metric_L2>;

int main()
{
    // Create simple matrix
    MatrixX3d matrix(10, 3);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        double f_i = static_cast<double>(i);
        matrix.row(i) = Vector3d(f_i, 0, 0);
    }

    // Create test points
    std::vector<Vector3d> test_vecs;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        double f_i = static_cast<double>(i);
        test_vecs.push_back(Vector3d(f_i, f_i, f_i));
    }
    
    // Result buffer
    double distance;
    size_t index;
    KNNResultSet<double> result_set(1);
    result_set.init(&index, &distance);
    SearchParams sp;
    // KDTree
    kdt matrix_index(3, std::ref(matrix), 10);
    matrix_index.index->buildIndex();

    //Query points backwards
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Vector3d curr_vec = test_vecs.at(i);
        matrix_index.index->findNeighbors(result_set, &curr_vec[0], sp);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << index << " " << distance << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    // Query points forwards
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Vector3d curr_vec = test_vecs.at(i);
        matrix_index.index->findNeighbors(result_set, &curr_vec[0], sp);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << index << " " << distance << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The backward query (`BQ`) returns the expected results. However the forward query (`FQ`) only yields zeros (both index and distance). `FQ` also seems to break the KDTree altogether. If you change the order of the two queries (the last two for loops), so that `FQ` is performed before `BQ` both will now only yield zeros.

Why does that behavior occur and how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set appears to be stateful - it's always showing you the nearest overall neighbor of all the points. For instance, if you loop from 5 to 10 you get `5 50` for each iteration

Reinitialize the result set each iteration and you'll get your desired behavior:

```cpp
result_set.init(&index, &distance);
matrix_index.index->findNeighbors(result_set, &curr_vec[0], sp);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/s5f1jq

Comment: This solves the issues I'm facing, however I'd like to understand why this error occurred in the first place. I can see, that the `init`-function resets some `counter`-variable of the `KNNResultSet` but it's still a little cryptic to me, what this counter does in the first place and why the error seems to be this "random".

Comment: The only place `count` gets used is in `addPoint`, which appears to maintain a list of the N points with the lowest distance (only displacing a point if it's lower). If the first location you look up has a distance of 0, it's never going to displace that, which is why it was all zeros.